# How to add left margin and wrap long lines in code tag

Tags: html, css

I have code like this:

```css
code {
  width: 520px;
  margin: 0 0 30px 200px;
}
```

```html
<code>
  &lt;script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.terminal/0.10.4/js/jquery.terminal.min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;<br/>
  &lt;link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.terminal/0.10.4/css/jquery.terminal.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/&gt;
</code>
```

but the margin is added only to the first line, I've try to add `white-space: pre-wrap;` with this css (found on [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/make-pre-text-wrap/)):

```
 white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
 white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
 white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
 white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
 word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
```

but then I don't have margin at all. How can I add margin to code tag and make text wrap if too big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adjusting how the `<code>` element itself is displayed by using `display: block`, which can affect how properties like `padding` or `margin` are applied:

```
code {
    display: block;
    width: 520px;
    margin: 0 0 30px 200px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

**Example**

You can [see an interactive example of this in action here](http://jsbin.com/polilu/edit?html,css,output) and what it looks like below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I need to add wrapper:

```css
.code_wrapper {
  width: 520px;
  margin: 0 0 30px 200px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
  white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
  white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
  white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
  word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

```html
<div class="code_wrapper">
<code>
  &lt;script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.terminal/0.10.4/js/jquery.terminal.min.js"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;<br/>
  &lt;link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.terminal/0.10.4/css/jquery.terminal.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/&gt;
</code>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put  `inside a div like this:`

```
<div class='outer_code' >
    <code>...</code>
</div>
```

Then in CSS

```
  .outer_code{
        width: 520px;
margin: 0 0 30px 200px;
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
word-wrap: break-word; 
    }
```